# Subprocess doesn't wait and makes PhantomJS crash

Tags: python, pdf, flask, python-requests

I have two scripts running, one on port :80 and one on port :81. Because some of our users are having issues with stuff happening on the server with port :81, I'm trying to implement a workaround like this;

*Old* way of doing it, which works fine for most users:

- AngularJS app makes request to `example.com:81/getpdf/1`
- Flask server generates PNG and PDF files using PhantomJS and ImageMagick using two separate `subprocess.Popen` calls and the `.wait()` method
- Using Flask's `send_file()`, the PDF gets sent back to the user and starts downloading

My workaround for this issue:

- AngularJS makes request to `example.com/getpdf/1`
- Flask server (`:80`) makes a new GET request, `r = requests.get(url_with_port_81)`, faking the old AngularJS request to create the PNG/PDF
- Instead of using `send_file()`, I now return the path of the generated PDF
- I return `send_file(r.text)`

Now, using my workaround, the subprocesses I run to create the PNG/PDFs somehow crash. I have to `sudo pkill python`, and only when I do so, I'm getting a PNG with no data in the folder on my server.

Basically, PhantomJS has run but hasn't loaded any data (only html/css, but no important stuff that needs to come from the Flask server) and crashes. How is this even possible? I'm just faking the request the browser makes using `requests.get`, or am I not aware of something here?

I thought `subprocess.Popen` is *non-blocking*, so my requests for data could still be answered to fill the PNG/PDFs?

Comment: Sorry, it's difficult to determine what is really going on here, especially since we don't get to see ANY of the code that is doing this. You have one thing (a flask app) calling another thing (another flask app) doing another thing (a process using PhantomJS and ImageMagick). See if you can remove pieces until you're down to a bare minimum that you can post that we can run to duplicate the problem. Otherwise, it is going to be very difficult for us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the reason my `subprocess` kept crashing. 
Apparently, it's a bug in Python < 2.7.3, described here: http://bugs.python.org/issue12786

I had to use `'close_fds=True'` in my `Popen` call and all was fixed. Thanks for your effort either way, @Mark Hildreth!